# Android Studio - Include remote AAR (Github for example)

Tags: android-studio, github, gradle, amazon-s3, aar

So I have an android shared library I am using. It's in AAR format.
I currently have it on Github all built and ready to go.

In my other project I want to include said library to use. How would I go about doing this? It currently sits on Github and could possibly be put on S3. Don't want to use some extra paid tool like Jitpack in this situation.

What route should I take?